# Issue with downloading file using Flask "send_from_directory" after AJAX post

Tags: python, flask, download

I have a button, "view purchase order", that sends an ajax post when clicked. Once the post is submitted, a file is downloaded from dropbox and saved into a directory named "temp_files". This action works just fine. However, the code does not follow the redirect to the download-file url.

I've tried telling ajax to follow the redirect on a successful post, I've also tried returning the file as an attachment. Neither have worked. I can find the URL for the file within the network tab, which I can double click and begins downloading the file.

Here is the route that handles the AJAX post and the route for the file download:

```
@tables_bp.route('/purchase_orders', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def purchase_orders():
    table = 'purchase_orders'
    # populate render_dict which helps make render_template
    # less verbose
    render_dict = helpers.render_args(table)
    # purchase order form creation
    po_form = PurchaseOrderForm()
... some other code ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        po = request.form['po']
        oath2 = os.environ.get('OATH2')
        po_folder = os.environ.get('PO_FOLDER')
        helpers.Dropbox_Excel_Worker(
            po_folder, po, oath2, PurchaseOrders
        )
        return redirect(url_for('tables.file_view', filename="temp_po.xlsx"))
... other form handlers below ...
```

```
@tables_bp.route('/purchase_orders/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def file_view(filename):
    return send_from_directory(current_app.config['TEMP_FILES'], filename)
```

And here is the helpers.Dropbox_Excel_Worker function that is successfully downloading the file and saving it within the temp_files directory.

```
def Dropbox_Excel_Worker(file_folder, po_num, oath2, PurchaseOrders):
    file = "/{}.xlsx".format(po_num)
    try:
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(oath2)
        metadata, res = dbx.files_download(file_folder + file)

        with closing(res) as result:
            byte_data = res.content
            file_stream = io.BytesIO(byte_data)

        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_stream)
        application = current_app._get_current_object()
        with application.app_context():
            file_name = secure_filename("temp_po.xlsx")
            temp_file = os.path.join(current_app.config['TEMP_FILES'], file_name)
            workbook.save(temp_file)
```

Sometimes the flask console returns both:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2019 15:49:42] "POST /tables/purchase_orders HTTP/1.1" 302 -
C:\Users\napaf\Desktop\programming\adco_flask\temp_files
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2019 15:49:42] "GET /tables/purchase_orders/temp_po.xlsx HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and other times it only returns the POST being successful. I'm not sure why, but this information might be helpful. In either case, the file does not begin downloading.
EDIT: I have it so it always returns the GET for the excel file. Which I can still find and download in the network tab using chrome's developer tools. It still doesn't return the file automatically though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring a workaround. If anyone can comment on the security of this, please do. Within the javascript I changed the ajax success to:

```
success: function(){
            $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            location.href = "/tables/purchase_orders/temp_po.xlsx";
```

which now successfully downloads the file.